# How to use enviroment variables in Svelte @ index.html

Tags: svelte, vite, sveltekit

I would like to use a environmental variable in `svelte-kit` project but unfornutaely I'm not being able to.

I have tried to:

*app.html*

```html
<meta name="TESTING" value="%VITE_GOOGLE_TAG%">
<meta name="TESTING" value="<% VITE_GOOGLE_TAG %>">
<meta name="TESTING" value="<% process.env.VITE_GOOGLE_TAG %>">
```

In my `.env` I have the variable defined:

```
VITE_GOOGLE_TAG=xxxxx
```

But the substitution doesn't happen when I re-start my server.

I'm looking to have a different `Google tag manager id` for each enviroment. Something like

```
staging -> xxxxx
production -> yyyyy
```

How can I access enviromental variables in `svelte-kit` in my `app.html`?

Comment: Did you tried to just use the svelte's `<svelte:head>` component that makes it possible to insert elements into `document.head`? Read more about it here https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-svelte-head

Comment: @johannchopin yeah. I was overly complicating things. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/seo#manual-setup-title-and-meta) describe adding `<meta>` tags to `<head>` by using [`<svelte:head>`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-svelte-head). If you want that `<meta>` tag to be present on all pages, that's probably best added to a common layout file (e.g., `src/routes/__layout.svelte`).

You can access [environment variables](https://kit.svelte.dev/faq#env-vars) via `import.meta.env.VARNAME`. And you can bind that to `<meta>.value` with Svelte's attribute binding syntax (i.e., the expression surrounded by curly brackets).

```html
<!-- src/routes/__layout.svelte -->
<svelte:head>
  <meta name="TESTING" value={import.meta.env.VITE_GOOGLE_TAG}>
</svelte:head>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltejs-kit-meta-tag-in-head?file=src%2Froutes%2F__layout.svelte)